# can't install scrapy for Python 2.7 on OS X El Capitan v10.11.4

Tags: python

```
OS X El Capitan v10.11.4
Last login: Sat Apr  9 02:10:00 on ttys000
Fanng-Mac-mini:~ Fanng$ sudo pip install six
The directory '/Users/Fanng/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled.Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/Fanng/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: Your running pip with sudo right?

Comment: This is the output of `pip install six` when the question is about `scrapy`. Also this output is a warning (that caching is disabled), not an error. It succeeds  at installing `six` because it is already installed.